# Exit sub after cancelling an InputBox

Tags: vba, excel

I'm making an inputbox that allows the user to enter a password into it, and I'd like it to be able to contain both text and numbers. If possible, I'd like it to allow special characters as well.

What I'm currently for the InputBox is this:

```
Sub NewPass()
Dim Pass As String, OldPass As String, ws As Worksheet

OldPass = Ark2.Range("B6").Value
Pass = Application.InputBox("Enter new password", Type:=2)
If Not Pass = vbNullString Then

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Unprotect Password:=OldPass
        ws.Protect Password:=Pass, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    Next

    Ark2.Range("B6").Value = Kode

End If
End Sub
```

But for some reason it still enters the loop when hitting cancel or the X in the corner of the prompt.

I've tried my luck with `VbNullString`, `0` and `""` but so far none of them works, and 0 ends with a `Run-time Error '13': Type Mismatch` in the if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `pass = vbNullString` as your condition you can use `pass = FALSE`  When a user hits cancel it puts the value 'FALSE' in your variable.

Since you are using an `application.inputbox` when the user hits cancel it will return FALSE instead of being null.  If you used just `pass = inputbox(...)` it would give you a null string.

When the user clicks 'ok' with the `application.inputbox`; leaving the field blank, the output will be a null string.

One of the big advantages of the `application.inputbox` is that it can put restrictions on what the user can type in.  If you do not want any restrictions, the inputbox function will be better.  It returns a null when the users clicks 'ok' without typing anything in and when the user hits 'cancel'

```
 Sub NewPass()
 Dim Pass As String, OldPass As String, ws As Worksheet

 OldPass = Ark2.Range("B6").Value
 Pass = InputBox("Enter new password")
 If Not Pass = VBNullSTring Then

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Unprotect Password:=OldPass
        ws.Protect Password:=Pass, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    Next

Ark2.Range(WB6").Value = Kode

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Might need to cover leaving the input box blank and clicking OK as well.

Comment: Right, I forgot that option. I've actually done that, but when I do that, then for some reason I'm no longer allowed to input characters of any kind. It suddenly only allows numbers. Even if the InputBox is left blank and I hit okay, I will end up with a Run-time Error '13': Type Mismatch

Comment: If you want to restrict what the user can type the `application.inputbox` is the way to go.  So you want to have the 'FALSE` condition to catch if the user hit the cancel box.  You can see this link for differences between the application.inputbox and the inputbox function. http://access-excel.tips/difference-inputbox-application-inputbox/

Comment: According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-inputbox-method-excel), *'for an input box that can accept both text and numbers, set Type to 1 + 2'*.

Comment: I tried that too, but I ended up with even more errors, so in the end I went back to type:=2. Using `Not Pass = False` was the only thing that cancelled the box as I wanted, but in turn that did not allow characters. Not with `Type:=2`, `Type:=1+2` or `Type:=3`. Going to an ordinary `InputBox` rather than and `Application.InputBox` and then using `Not Pass = VbNullString` works for me as I don't want to restrict the users coices when it comes to passwords

Comment: @ChristianEmilJohansen I'm sorry.  I got it backwards and thought that you wanted to restrict the characters for the password even though your question was clear.  In that case I would recommend what you have done.  Just going to the inputbox function should work better.  Plus you don't have to worry about writing code to find if a user entered a blank password or if the user hit the cancel button.  Both will return null.  I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the help as well as the information. I had no idea the two were different